# Yii2 display data using for each loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops, model-view-controller, yii2

Using yii2 I have created a Model and CRUD using gii.

I want to use a foreach or while loop in my VIEW to display the data in the following format

For each row in database table

```
echo("addMarker($lat_field, $lon_field);\n");
```

I have an index page which is rendered using the following controller action.

```
    public function actionIndex()
{
    $this->layout = 'directory';

    $searchModel = new ShopDirectorySearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

I can use the following to display the data using listview which displays all the data/rows within database however it has html around it and obviously isn't outputted in the format I wish it to be.

```
    <?=  ListView::widget([
 'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
 'itemOptions' => ['class' => 'col-xs-6 col-sm-3'],
 'itemView' => '_index',
]);?>
```

Answer (score 18):

No need to use ListView here, you should simply try :

```
foreach ($dataProvider->models as $model) {
    echo "addMarker({$model->lat_field}, {$model->lon_field});";
}
```

If you really want to use ListView, you could simply edit `_index` view file.

Comment: Your solution looks perfect I didn't want to use list view I was just unsure on how to display data in yii2 with using one of there widgets.

Comment: Thanks It's Working for me

Answer (score 3):

```
if(!empty($st_data))
    {
        foreach($st_data as $row)
        {
            echo 'Country Name: '.$row['country_name'].'</br>';
            echo 'State Name: '.$row['state_name'].'</br>';
            echo 'City Name: '.$row['city_name'].'</br>';
            echo '</br>';
        }
        exit;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$rows = ShopDirectory::findAll();
if(!empty($rows))
{
  foreach($rows as $row)
  {
    $lat = $row->lat;
    $lon = $row->lon;

    $this->view->registerJs('addmarker("'.$lat.'", "'.$lon.'"."\n");', yii\web\View::POS_END);
    ...
  }
}
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/61940-simple-while-loop-to-list-all-rows/page__view__findpost__p__274731