# Yii2-advanced : ArrayDataProvider

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to use `ArrayDataProvider` with the following code of siteController. I wrote the following code but it doesn't work. 
Here is my actionIndex :

```
public function actionIndex()
{
        $query = new \yii\db\Query;
        $query->select('*')->from('business_main_categories');
        $query->createCommand();

        $dataProviders = [];

        foreach ($query as $category) {
            $dataProviders[] = new ArrayDataProvider([
                'allModels' => $category,
                'sort' => false,
                'pagination' => false,
            ]);
        }

        return $this->render('index', [
            'dataProvider' => $dataProviders,
        ]);
}
```

And want it to iterate in gridView. So, I wrote the following code (I don't know whether it's correct or not) :

Here is my index.php :

```
<?php
    $dataProviders[] = 'dataProvider';
    foreach ($dataProviders as $dataProvider) {
        echo GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'summary' => '',
            'columns' => [
                [
                        'attribute' => 'bmc_image',
                        'format' => 'html',
                        'label' => '',
                        'value' => function ($data) {
                            return Html::img($data['bmc_image'],
                                ['width' => '210px', 'height' => '190px']);
                        },
                    ],
                ]
       ]); 
    } 
?>
```

Comment: PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException  : Call to a member function getCount() on string.                                                                                     in C:\xampp\htdocs\efa-webv1\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\widgets\BaseListView.php

Comment: Refer: http://www.sitepoint.com/rendering-data-in-yii-2-with-gridview-and-listview/

Comment: thanks. I will try & let you know if worked.

Comment: Helpful: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-arraydataprovider.html

Comment: Actually I know how to work with gridview. But not able to understand how to iterate it in a loop. So, please help me about this.

Comment: ok...i will post my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem without using gridview. As follows -

My SiteController -

```
public function actionIndex()
{
        $searchModel = new BusinessMainCategoriesSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
        $dataProvider->pagination->pageSize = $dataProvider->getTotalCount();   //-1 : disable

        return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
}
```

using this code I get all records in dataProvider from my db.
(Note that, I'm using ActiveDataProvider in my 'BusinessMainCategoriesSearch' model)

And, my index.php is -

```
<?php
    $m = $dataProvider->getModels();
    foreach ($m as $dp) {
        echo "<img src = '".$dp['bmc_image']."' />";
        echo '<center><font color = "white">'.$dp['bmc_name'].'<font/></center>';
    } 
?>
```

It worked great for me & it's a easiest way to do so.

Answer (score 1):

**Controller**

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $query = new \yii\db\Query;
    $dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([
    'allModels' =>$query->from('business_main_categories')->all(),
    ]);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

**Index**

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
             [
              'attribute' => 'bmc_image',
              'format' => 'html',               
               'value' => function ($data) {
                    return Html::img($data['bmc_image'],['width' => '210px', 'height' => '190px']);
                   },
             ],
        ],
]); ?>
```

Comment: Yeah, this works for me; but I don't want all records at once in my index.php . I need a different gridView for each & every record, that's why I'm writing it in a loop shown above. (So that I will get different 'bmc_image' for different record).

Comment: That is, suppose I've 20 records in a db. Then, here I've to take records one by one & apply a gridview for each one.(in index.php). But with the code suggested by you, it takes all 20 records in a same gridview, but it's not what I expected to be shown in my template.

Comment: @TusharWalzade.  `foreach ($dataProvider->models as $model) { echo gridview}`

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28618043/yii2-display-data-using-for-each-loop

Comment: actually it couldn't get dataProvider before/outside the gridView

Comment: I think there is an error near my index.php's 1st statement =>  $dataProviders[] = 'dataProvider';    I tried to echo 'hi' instead of gridview but though it shows the error - 
 
Trying to get property of non-object.       If I tried to print $dataProvider, it says -  PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException : Array to string conversion

Comment: Is anyone there who understood my question & can help me?